# Access Android C++ NNAPIs - ANeuralNetworksCompilation_createForDevices gives error

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, nnapi

Trying to Access GPU using Android C++ NNAPIs ANeuralNetworksCompilation_createForDevices gives error
ANeuralNetworksCompilation_createForDevices gives error

Linking fails.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

minimum sdk must be set 29.
it was set to 27 earlier, so was not working